# Search for presence of a blank space inside a string using find

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
std::string t = "11:05:47"  (No spaces inside)
```

I want to check if it has an empty space in it (which it doesnt) so I am using

```
       unsigned present = t.find(" ");
       if (present!=std::string::npos)
       {
             //Ends up in here
       }
```

The codes seems to think there is a blank space inside the string any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong

Here are the results
present = 4294967295
t = 11:15:36

IS there a boost library that could help me do this ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: This looks good to me. Try printing out both `t` and `present` -- that'll probably give us some more insight.

Comment: Use `std::string::size_type`, or `auto`, for type of `present`.

Comment: Don`t use `unsigned` for the type here, use `size_t` as this is the actual return type of `find`

Comment: `warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]` - Either turn up your warning level or decide to include the warning you get in the post.

Comment: @BoBTFish: That *is* the problem. If `unsigned` is 32-bits and `size_t` is 64-bits (commonly is), then there's no hope that any value of `present` can compare equal to `npos`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `unsigned`. [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) returns a `std::string::size_type`, which is usually `size_t`.

```
std::string::size_type present = t.find(" ");
if (present!=std::string::npos) {

}
```

As pointed out by others, you could use C++11's `auto` to let the compiler deduce what the type of `present` should be:

```
auto present = t.find(" ");
```